# Using same component for new and existing form records without ngChanges

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components, a parent and a child component. Between them they can serve urls for new and existing records. ie `applications/add` AND `applications/:guid`

I currently have this for my **parent** component:

HTML:

```
<app-university-applications-form
    [existingData]="(existingFormData$ | async)!"
></app-university-applications-form>
```

TS:

```
existingFormData$: Observable<UniversityApplicationsDetail> = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    map(params => params['id']),
    filter(id => !!id),
    switchMap((id: string) => this.httpService.getUniversityApplicationsDetail(id))
  );
```

And the following for my **child** component:

TS

```
@Input() existingData!: UniversityApplicationsDetail; //Using ! here is the "non-null assertion operator"

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if ((this.existingData !== null)){
      this.title.setTitle("Update University Application");
      this.populateForm();
    }
  }
```

And this works all fine.
But I want to avoid using `ngOnChanges` and do everything from `ngOnit` in the **child** component.

If I change the **parent** component to:

html

```
<app-university-applications-form
    *ngIf="(existingFormData$ | async)! as detail"
    [existingData]="detail"
></app-university-applications-form>
```

And the **child** component to:

TS

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.title.setTitle("New University Application");
    this.createForm();

    if ((this.existingData !== null)){
      this.title.setTitle("Update University Application");
      this.populateForm();
    }
  }
```

Then the form displays when on existing record mode but not on new record mode. How can I fix this?

Comment: I would use some property like `showForm` in the `*ngIf` and move `(existingFormData$ | async)!` to the `[existingData]` input property. Somewhere in your parent component there should be a way to navigate to the chidl component. Set the `showForm` in this method to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1

You could create a second observable `isNewRecord$` that resolves to `true` whenever `id` is `null`. And if `isNewRecord$` resolves to `true` you trigger the rendering of `app-university-applications-form` without passing a value to the input-property `[existingData]`.

The **Parent TS**:

```
id$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    map(params => params['id'])
);

// Will emit a value whenever an id is provided:
existingFormData$ = this.id$.pipe(
    filter(id => !!id),
    switchMap((id: string) => this.httpService.getUniversityApplicationsDetail(id))
);

// Will be true whenever *no* id is provided:
isNewRecord$ = this.id$.pipe(
    filter(id => !id),
    map(() => true)
);
```

The **Parent HTML**:

```
<app-university-applications-form
    *ngIf="(existingFormData$ | async)! as detail"
    [existingData]="detail">
</app-university-applications-form>

<app-university-applications-form
    *ngIf="isNewRecord$  | async">
</app-university-applications-form>
```

---

#### Solution 2

If you want just one `app-university-applications-form` in your html, you could do the following:

- In case there is an ID, pass the object that is returned from the backend
- In case there is *no* ID, you also pass an object of the same type, but let's say with the property `id: undefined`. Therefore you will know in your child-component, if id === undefined, it must be a new record.

The corresponding **Parent TS** might look as follows:

```
existingFormData$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    map(params => params['id']),
    switchMap((id: string) => !!id ?
      this.httpService.getUniversityApplicationsDetail(id) : of({ id: undefined }))
);
```

**Parent HTML**:

```
<app-university-applications-form
    *ngIf="(existingFormData$ | async)! as detail"
    [existingData]="detail">
</app-university-applications-form>
```

**Child TS**:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.title.setTitle("New University Application");
    this.createForm();
    
    // Check if a particular property is set, to determine whether its a new record:
    if (this.existingData.id) {
      this.title.setTitle("Update University Application");
      this.populateForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that works great. Do you think there might be any other way of just having the 1 <app-university-applications-form> instead of the 2? Can the 2 async be combined into 1 *ngIf?

Comment: I added an alternative solution, that might fit your needs.

Comment: I decided to use your first solution as it separates concerns alot more and I was getting complicated type checking problems in the alternative solution.